# Changing video thumbnail_link in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Can I update or change the thumbnail_link for a video in Facebook?

I access the video attributes with this query:

```
$facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => "SELECT vid, thumbnail_link FROM video WHERE owner='$user_id' AND vid=22170513xxxxx" ));
```

Now, if I want to change the thumbnail image for the video, how can I do it?
I tried the [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language):

```
'query' => "UPDATE video SET thumbnail_link ='xyz'  WHERE owner='$user_id' AND vid=22170521xxxx"
```

But it doesn't work, so what can be the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FQL is only for querying data exposed by the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API), so you can only fetch data. You can read the documentation in *[Facebook Query Language (FQL)](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)*.

Queries are of the form:

```
SELECT [fields] FROM [table] WHERE [conditions].
```